# Is it fine to call localStorage.getItem in React render?

Tags: reactjs, performance, local-storage

Is it ok from a performance point of view to call `localStorage.getItem()` at render phase?
Like this:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Button text={localStorage.getItem('my-key')} />
  );
}
```

Comment: You should not if the localstorage item changes your component wont rerender automatically

Comment: @yqlim Looks like performance is pretty low comparing to usual ES objects. I can infer that it's better no to use localStorage.getItem at render phase. Thank you.